# MQL - Incorrect data reading or Incorrect data parsing: Integer Array to Char Array Buffer

Tags: java, arrays, named-pipes

I am working in MQL to receive some data from NamedPipes. The communication works well, the data is received but I am having problems with the conversion of the data from an array of integers to the string message actually sent.

Here is the code I am using:

```
string StringFromBuffer(int &buffer[], int length) {
   string message = "";
   for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      int c = buffer[i / 4];
      int off = i % 4;
      int shift = 0;
      if ( off == 1 )
         shift = 8;
      else if ( off == 2 )
         shift = 16;
      else if ( off == 3 )
         shift = 24;
      c = (c >> shift) & 0xff;
      message = message + CharToStr( c );
   }       
   return( message );
}
```

This is supposed to return the message from the integer buffer, but this is what happens, when I send from the NamedPipes Server the String "1234567890" then the client receives (or converts the data received to) this "12345678". So, instead of parsing 10 numbers, it only retrieves 8 of them. Now, if I send again the same sequence of numbers "1234567890", then the client receives (or parses) the last two numbers it didn't parse it the previous message plus then eight numbers, to then show this on screen: "9012345678". And if I repeat the sequence, I continue to get the same values, first eight numbers then ten numbers and so on.

I know the NamedPipes are sending the correct Strings because I also have a Java NamedPipes client which receives data from the same NamedPipes server, and it receives the correct amount of data, and shows on screen the exact String sent. So the problem is not the server but this client, which is either not reading correctly or not parsing correctly.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.-

Comment: You forgot to add Python, C# and COBOL tags

Comment: Of course not! It should have been Ruby, Fortran and BASIC.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using simple "IntegerToString" function?
(http://docs.mql4.com/convert/integertostring)

```
string StringFromBuffer(int buffer[], int length) {
   string message = "";
   for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      message = message + IntegerToString( buffer[i] );
   }       
   return( message );
}
```

Comment: Because it is not C++, it is MQL. Hence, I need a raw, low level implementation of this method.